# phonegap for webos eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, webos

I am developing Palm Pre apps using the Eclipse IDE. How to setup Phonegap with Eclipse for developing cross-platform apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get PhoneGap working on webOS, check out the Palm Developer Blog posts at http://developer.palm.com/blog/2010/09/developing-cross-platform-apps-with-phone-gap-part-1/.  If you're using Mac OS X or Linux, Phonegap should work out-of-the-box.  On Windows, you'll need to alter the makefile to use "cmd /c" in front of the palm-install and palm-package commands to get Make to run the batch files correctly.